# How to make wall faces for this object?

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

I have this object:

[image: object]

I want to make wall faces for all of its outer edges, but only on the top, so there should be no faces on the bottom of those edges.

[image: outer edges]

I have tried Loft and Bridge from LoopTools, and I also tried to select them all then press <kbd>F</kbd>, which obviously just makes a lot of faces connecting each edge to each other edge.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to achieve? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @AdamTM Glenn van Acker has understood what I mean, so maybe you should the first part of his answer to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you want this mesh on one side of a box shaped mesh? if so, you should extrude those edges over the Z-axis, then scale the resulting edges 
 to 0 over the Z-axis, and make a face on those edges.
shortcut to extrude over Z-axis: E->Z, followed by a value, or move with the mouse.
then to scale : S-> Z-> 0 to make it flat.
then press F with those edges selected, which will make a face.
As you pointed out yourself, answering your own question, you could use checker deselect to select every other vertex, and dissolve them.

Comment: This does make the faces I need, but they are split in half with an edge extruded from the middle vertex of each triangle, which is something I do not want.

Comment: well then i don't think there's any simple method to do this. you should probably do it manually then. or make a plane beneath the object, and then make a face for each side.
another method may be to bake a normal map for a simple box shape.

Comment: I will try checker deselecting selecting the result vertices then dissolving the once that are left selected. if the checker deselect actually keeps only the vertices that I don't want then it will be easy to remove them.